# Tiling rule is not always enforced

Tags: awesome-wm

I am a long term user of XMonad trying Awesome for its more advanced ways of tiling.

**What I did:**

Opened an empty libreoffice window in a tiled workspace with several other windows opened.
This window follows the tiling rule.
Then loaded in this window a document.

**What I expected:**

Window doesn't change its height of width

**What I got:**

window suddenly went maximized.

**Supplementary information:**

last time this document was used it was probably maximized.

How can I force libreoffice to obey the tiling rule?

TIA